# How to overwrite Devise session#create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have valid autentication which autenticate user by tables users.

But in this table i have boolean field ( "corrected" => true/false )

How can i autenticate users which has field "corrected: true" ONLY.

I try to overwrite method create ( under this text ), but i dont understand how how to do it exactly.

```
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)

    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
```

thn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add another field to validate the authentication.
I resolved my task: 
in Devise i rewrite method:

```
  def self.find_for_authentication(tainted_conditions)
    super(tainted_conditions.reverse_merge(type: 'User'))
  end
```

its final version.

> Next links on methods - which is used when hero start session:

Create:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L14

Authenticate:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb#L7

find_for_database_authentication:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L135

find_for_authentication:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L241

find_first_by_auth_conditions:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L245

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite the create action then you have to create a separate controller by the name of users and add the action which you want to overwrite.Devise generate model and view for us, but doesn't have any controller. So if you want to overwrite any action , just create the controller and add the action.